# track moving object with rectangle using javacv opencv

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

Im currently doing a part of project to create rectangles around moving object in a video using javacv . I used this code and when i run this i got an  error called "This pointer address is null". anyone can help me ? thank you

```
    while(true) {
        colourImage = cvQueryFrame( capture );

    if( colourImage==null ) break;

    //If this is the first time, initialize the images.
    if(first)
    {
    difference = colourImage.clone();
    temp = colourImage.clone();  

    cvConvertScale(colourImage, movingAverage, 1.0, 0.0);
first = false;
    }       

    //else, make a running average of the motion.
    else
    {

    cvRunningAvg(colourImage, movingAverage, 0.020, null);
    }


    //Convert the scale of the moving average.
    cvConvertScale(movingAverage,temp, 1.0, 0.0);

    //Minus the current frame from the moving average.
    cvAbsDiff(colourImage, temp, difference);


    //Convert the image to grayscale.
    cvCvtColor(difference,greyImage,CV_RGB2GRAY);

    //Convert the image to black and white.
    cvThreshold(greyImage, greyImage, 70, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

    //Dilate and erode to get people blobs
    cvDilate(greyImage, greyImage, null, 18);

    cvErode(greyImage, greyImage, null, 10);


    CvSeq contour=new  CvSeq();
    CvMemStorage storage=CvMemStorage.create();
    cvFindContours(greyImage, storage, contour, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class), CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    System.out.println(contour.total());
```

Comment: A bit hard to read your posted code. Did you debug before asking this?

Comment: `contour.isNull()` can be `true` after `cvFindContours()` when no contours are detected. In that case, `contour.total()` will fail. Is this where the error occurs?